# Driver for nvidia 6200tc

Tags: drivers, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

I installed this GPU in PC and dont know what driver to download, when I search in Google there is a million drivers but none of them are on offical Nvidia website so I dont know which one to chose.

Comment: Always search first on the official website https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Search for GeForce > GeForce 6 Series

[image]

This takes you to https://www.nvidia.co.uk/Download/driverResults.aspx/82850/en-us which supports the following

[image]

Download and install that as a clean install, and you're good to go.

Comment: I did that and it says that it can not intall it.

Comment: Did you download the correct version for your operating system? Is there an install log somewhere? If there's no log, run the setup by running `setup.exe -log:"C:\NVlog" -loglevel:6`